# How to manage multiple-level nesting route in react-router v4?

Tags: react-router

I think the new way to nest children route in react-router v4 is **difficult to read/maintain/reuse**, do I using the wrong way?

V2 is clear, but code in V4 is expand（many match.url）, below.

```
{/* v2 */}
<Route path='/:bizType'>
    <Route path=':module'>
       <Route path='demo1' component={Demo1} />
    </Route>
</Route>

{/* v4 */}
<Route path='/:bizType' component={({match})=>{
    return <Route path={`${match.url}/:module`} component={({match})=>{
        return <div>
            <Route path={`${match.url}/demo1`} component={Demo1} />
        </div>
       }} />
    }}>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

your V4 way is awesome and I'll use it in my app. but I prefer to use external pure component.